# using session_destroy to deleting things in cart

Tags: php, session

I am  doing a e-commerce website.
I would like to clarify something.

Let say,
If I want to do a session_destroy to the session item that I've in my cart after I click on logout,
can I check with you, is it something like this?

```
<?php

$logout = "login.php";

if(isset($logout))
{
     session_destroy();
}


?>
```

Comment: Did you try it? Did it work?

Comment: I did work, but it isn't what I want.
it keep ask me to login whenever I click on home page to view the items(i didn't click logout).

Comment: Well, session_destroy removes all data in the session, including login info. Try usetting the indexes where you store cart info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`session_destroy()`  destroys all of the data associated with the current session. If you fine with it, you can use or rather use `unset` to clear any specific session with specifying it's key like: `unset($_SESSION['cart_items']);`

[Reference](https://www.php.net/session_destroy).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21134121/unset-session-does-not-work-well-php
can help?

Answer (score 0):

In your example `isset($logout)` always return TRUE and you destroy session every execution of script. Is it that you want?